# loadhtmlstring shows blank screen webview ios10

Tags: webview, ios10

`loadhtmlstring` for web view shows blank screen in  `iOS10`

```
 [webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='font-size:13px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#0000;word-break:keep-all'>%@",myshtmalstring] baseURL:nil];
```

when loaded shows blank screen

Comment: worked by giving color:#000 instead of color :#000 , as follows strict coding constraints